# Matplotlib performance on pan

Tags: python, matplotlib

I working on a PyQt GUI in order to plot 2D/3D data.
Matplotlib is very interesting concerning all its available features.
However, Matplotlib seems to not be relevant when you have huge amount of data (for instance 10000x10000). I found that maybe GTKAgg backend is really efficient for this issue, but not really.

Maybe you can help me in order to enhance the performance of matplotlib when you want to pan or zoom in the figure.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mpl.use('GTK3Agg')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
n = 10000
Z = np.random.randint(10,size=(n,n))

ax.imshow(Z)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Depending on the application, you could consider only showing a subset, e.g. `ax.imshow(Z[::10,::10])` would skip 99% of the points.

Comment: No unfortunately it's really important to show every point on the graph.

Comment: Well, such a thing will be slow. To make it faster, you might need to show a subset when zoomed out, and different subsets when zoomed in. See e.g. [custom zoom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68733904/python-matplotlib-custom-zoom-function-isnt-working) for some inspiration.